# how to simplify the <select> in angular

Tags: angularjs, select, controller, directive

I have a `<select>` dropdown with so many attributes, it hurts just to look at it in the html file. What's the best way to refactor this, using angular, into something easier on the eyes? Set this up in a controller? A directive maybe?

```
<select name="connection" id="connectionId" class="form-control"
    ng-init="selectedConnection = connections[0]"
    ng-change="onChangeConnection()"
    ng-model="selectedConnection"
    ng-options="connection for connection in connections"></select>
```

Comment: Well, you could move the `ng-init` into the controller and handle `ng-change` by watching the model. That only leaves `ng-model` and `ng-options` which are somewhat required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need `id`, and you certainly should not use `ng-init` - setting up the View Model variables should be done in the controller.

```
$scope.selectedConnection = $scope.connections[0]
```

You only need `name` if you intend to react to validation events on this `<select>`:

```
<form name="form1">
    <select ng-model="foo" name="fooSelect" required>...</select>
    <span ng-show="form1.fooSelect.$dirty && form1.fooSelect.$invalid">
       You must make a selection
    </span>
</form>
```

As for `ng-change`, I absolutely disagree with other suggestions about turning it into a `$watch`. `ng-change` serves a different purpose than `$watch` - it reacts to user-triggered events that change the model for the `select`. `$watch`, on the other hand, fires for a change coming from any sources. Not only that, but it is also evaluated on **every** digest cycle. It is thus, much more expensive and completely unnecessary here, and should not be done just for the sake of a pretty HTML.

If you are doing something in response to a user changing the selection, then you should keep it as `ng-change`.

Comment: If the `<select>` has a `<label>`, you need `id`

Comment: @Phil, unless you wrap it in the `<label>`

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the ng-init and put the initialization in a controller.

In the controller you should do like `$scope.selectedConnection= connections[0]`
An alternative for the ng-change in template is put a `$watch` in the controller related with the model selected connection.

```
$scope.$watch('selectedConnection', function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log("value changed")
}, true);
```

the function in `$watch` will call every time that a change is detected in the model.